# why Mybatis add a check request for all requests?

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, amazon-athena, hikaricp, spring-mybatis

I'm using Mybatis with spring boot 'mybatis-spring-boot-starter version 2.1.0' and Athena. When I check my database logs, there is two request for each request called by Mybatis :

the first one is : SELECT * FROM (myRequest) T LIMIT 0

And the second one is : myRequest

Like if he create a request to check the availability of database for each request, any Idea ?

here is my mapper :

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @Select(value = "select name, adress from db.table limit 10")
    List<Object> findAll();
}
```

and my database configuration

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class AthenaConfig {

    @Bean(name = "athena-db")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "athena.spring.datasource.hikari")
    public DataSource athenaDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory(@Qualifier("athena-db") DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setTypeAliasesPackage("athena.mapper");
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject().getConfiguration().setDefaultFetchSize(500);
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject().getConfiguration().setMapUnderscoreToCamelCase(true);
        return sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public MapperScannerConfigurer mapperScannerConfigurer() throws Exception {
        MapperScannerConfigurer mapperScannerConfigurer = new MapperScannerConfigurer();
        mapperScannerConfigurer.setBasePackage("athena.mapper");
        return mapperScannerConfigurer;
    }
}
```

Here is my application.properties file :

```
athena.spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver
athena.spring.datasource.url=jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=eu-west-1;AwsCredentialsProviderClass=com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;S3OutputLocation=s3://xxxx/;
```

when I use JDBC template I dont have extra queries, here is my test with JDBCTemplate :

```
@Repository
public class MyRepository {
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    List<Object> findAll(){
     return jdbcTemplate.query("select name, adress from db.table limit 10",new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Object.class));
    }
}
```

How can I avoid this useless call ? thanks in advance

Comment: mybatis by itself does not do any extra queries. Show you mybatis config if you use any and more importantly show us how is you `DataSource` configured.

Comment: @RomanKonoval i update my question, i add DataSource and my application.properties

Comment: Have you checked if you get the same query duplication when you execute query using plain JDBC? If that's the case then the JDBC driver does this internally.

Comment: In my understand, the MyBatis does not execute automatically first query such as "SELECT * FROM (myRequest) T LIMIT 0".  Does this happen when use pure JDBC? If happen, this issue does not belong the MyBatis.

Comment: When i use pure JDBC, i dont have the extra request, do you any idea ?

Comment: I think that it's hikari who did this behavior but can't find out how to bypass it, any help please ??

Comment: I think it's the driver trying to get the metadata. See the description of 'MetadataRetrievalMethod' in this [PDF](https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC_2.0.9/docs/Simba+Athena+JDBC+Driver+Install+and+Configuration+Guide.pdf). Make sure that your Athena uses Glue and the driver you're using is the latest. And, could you add the JDBC code to the question? I would like to verify something.

Comment: For jdbc code, I'm using simple call with spring jdbcTemplate like jdbcTemplate.query()...,

Comment: @Sfayn I wanted to know if your test used `java.sql.Statement` or `java.sql.PreparedStatement`. I suspect that this extra query is executed only when `PreparedStatement` is used. MyBatis uses `PreparedStatement` by default. In case of `JDBCTemplate#query()`, it depends. If you cannot post the test code, please verify it yourself. Also, have you verified that your Athena is using Glue?

Comment: @ave I update my question, i add the jdcTemplate test, I don't use preparedStatement, i think athena jdbc doesn't even support prepared statement, that's why I'm using mybatis to use string replacement instead. 
Yes my Athena is using Glue

Comment: @Sfayn There is no such method (i.e. `query(String sql)`) in [JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html), but it may use `Statement` if you don't specify `Object[]` argument. MyBatis uses `PreparedStatement` even if there is no variables to replace. Try adding `@Options(statementType = StatementType.STATEMENT)` to the mapper statement and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working, I don't have extra query anymore, is it possible to apply this for all queries without add annotation @Option.. to all mappers ?

Comment: @Sfayn Happy to hear it worked! Unfortunately, there is no option to configure statement type globally at the moment (it's a quite unusual requirement, as you could imagine). It might be worth contacting AWS tech support to ask if there is any other way to avoid the extra query. And if changing the statement type is the only way, please create a new feature request ticket on the [tracker](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues) with the background (i.e. the Athena situation) and we'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it worket by adding @Options(statementType = StatementType.STATEMENT) to my mapper:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @Select(value = "select name, adress from db.table limit 10")
    @Options(statementType = StatementType.STATEMENT)
    List<Object> findAll();
}
```

there is no extra request anymore thanks to @ave